# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me returns 403 for other users than myself

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have developed a small app using the [Express MSAL tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal) as the authentication mechanism.

I can log in and request my user info through https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me just fine.

However, if I switch to a test user (in the same domain) I get a 403 error when accessing https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me. Also confirmed this is happening to a colleague (also in the same domain)

Using [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), I can see that the access token I get for my own user has `scp: openid profile User.Read email` while my test user only gets `scp: openid profile email`. So I guess, it is working as intended. But, the question is - **how do I add User.Read to all users using the app?**

In the API permissions for my app in the Azure portal, I have `Delegated` `User.Read` as a permission. (I think this was added automatically)
[image: API permissions]

Comment: `switch to a test user (in the same domain) ` do you mean that you used the test user to sign in and call graph api to see user information?\

Comment: Looks like your colleague is missing the required scope User.Read in the token, Use Scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/.default , while issuing the token,  this will get all the scopes from Azure AD by default

Comment: @TinyWang: Correct. New browser with a test user

Comment: @DipeshJadhav: I think this is the answer. I just don't know how to do it. In the code I have a function `router.get('/acquireToken', ...` that has the scope set to `scopes: ["User.Read"]` as from the MSAL tutorial. Should this be changed? Why is it working for me, but nobody else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the user doesn't have the required permissions to perform the action:

[image]

**To resolve the error, try the below:**

I agree with *DipeshJadhav*, Generate the token with **scope** as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` :

[image]

The access token contains the **`user.read`** permission when decoded like below:

[image]

After passing the correct scope, I am able to read the user details successfully:

[image]

In your code try passing the scope as:
`scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]`

**If still the issue persists**, grant Admin consent to the API permission:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]` didn't work. In fact, it made things worse as I was also not able to log in even.

The strange thing is that I get prompted with a consent form saying it would need permission to read basic user info. I click approve, but cannot see my user as accepted in the backend.

Granting permissions as admin, however, worked! And is a better solution, as it doesn't require the users to consent to this app.

Thanks a million!